# Migrating from Cherokee to Apache?

Tags: apache, ubuntu-10.04, cherokee

Maybe this is just a simple install and configure... but I don't want to wreck all my sites with a careless move.

As much as I like Cherokee, I think I want to change my server environment to a more traditional LAMP setup.

Is there anything I need to worry about after moving to Apache? Aside from permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you need to worry about is about your rewrite rules. Unless you use specific server variables in your script, nothing else should break.

Answer (score 0):

Colum is right, rewrite rules are important, but also the modules used. I don't really know which features you are using from Cherokee, but probably you will need to load complementary modules to do the same in Apache.